# Convert timestamp string with timezone to 'dd/mm/yyyy' format

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller

I have an array which has the following dates as entries:

```
Mon Feb 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Feb 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Wed Feb 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Thu Feb 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**How can I remove the time zone and convert this date to `dd/mm/yyyy` format?** I need these with the `/` and return them to a grid column by column.

Example

```
 -               |[17/02/2020]   |   [18/02/2020]  |  [19/02/2020]
 1 -----         |     -         |    -            |  -
 2 -----         |     -         |    -            |  -
```

Comment: I need to get them like [17/02/2020]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to clean up your question, let me know whether I understood everything correctly, please.

Comment: Giving feedbacks about answers may help to address your problem more precisely. Just in case, you tried [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60335399/11299053) and failed, I may support you in troubleshooting up to the point it works for you so that you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may drop timezone part, convert that string into date and then back to the string of the suitable format:

```js
const dates = [
        'Mon Feb 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
        'Tue Feb 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
        'Wed Feb 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
        'Thu Feb 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
      ],
      result = dates.map(date => new Date(date.replace(/ GMT.*/,'')).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))
      
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks alot , I converted the string into a date and back to a string and it worked as you said...